# Unaccounted for 16MB RAM. vcgencmd and free showing different RAM available

Tags: debian

I'm running Debian Wheezy on a Model B+ which has 512MB of RAM. I've set `start_x=0` and `gpu_mem=16` in `/boot/config.txt` and the command `vcgencmd get_mem arm && vcgencmd get_mem gpu` is showing an expected:

```
arm=496M
gpu=16M
```

What isn't expected is that `free -h` only lists `480M` of RAM for the arm:

```
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          480M       411M        69M       4.4M        88M       261M
-/+ buffers/cache:        60M       419M
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

So I'm listed as having 480M total instead of 496M like `vcgencmd` shows. Why might this be? I thought this might because `free` presents it as mebibytes instead of megabytes but provided the conversion option `free -h --si` gives:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          491M       390M       101M        29M       116M       234M
-/+ buffers/cache:        39M       451M 
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Still 5MB short. What may the discrepancy be?

Answer (score 3):

`free` doesn't list RAM reserved for the Linux kernel code, which is between 2 and 10 MB, depending on configuration, so the missing 5 MB seem right.